# Get January 1st of next year

Tags: python, django

This really shouldn't be this hard but for some reason I can't seem to get it.

I am trying to run a filter on my query that compares the date range between today, and the first day of next year.

Getting today is no problem, but I can't seem to get the first day of next year.  I want to be able to provide myself with Jan 1/2013

Here is my filter so far:

```
cur_il = Investment.objects.all().filter(plan = plan).order_by('financial_institution').filter(maturity_date__range=[now, nextyear])
```

Obviously I use this to get today's date:

```
now = datetime.now()
```

How can I get the next date?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Does this work?

```
>>> today = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> next_year = datetime.datetime(year=today.year+1, month=1, day=1)
>>> next_year
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```